# mapbox with flutter_maps package

Tags: flutter, mapbox

i created a basic app to use mapbox with flutter_maps package, i get a blank screen..
i connected a mobile phone, i didn't use the emulator...
i removed my private access token for obvious reasons...

thanks in advance...

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';


void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FlutterMap(
        options: MapOptions(minZoom: 10.0),
        layers: [
          TileLayerOptions(
            urlTemplate:"https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/hazem-saeed/ck9b1uisj0oht1iplyruetv9q/wmts?access_token=access_token",
            additionalOptions: {
              'accessToken':"access_token",
              'id': 'mapbox.mapbox-streets-v7'
            }
          )
        ]
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct urlTemplate is

```
https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token={accessToken}
```

WMTS is not supported in fluttter_map

Comment: then what should i choose from the droplist in the mapbox website?

Comment: CARTO as far as I know

Comment: i used your method above, still got a blank screen... then i went to mapbox website, changed it Carto, still a blank screen!! and i used here maps as well, still a blank screen...
thanks for your efforts, though... i appreciate it...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar situation. But looking closer I realized that the blank screen was the map drawn with a lot of zoom in the ocean. So I zoomed out and the map appeared.